# next.config.js load options conditonally based on .env

Tags: next.js

i am trying to load options in `next.config.js` based on env variables.
I did check out the documentation https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/introduction which states i can use functions but it doenst seem to work.
Error is `hostname "storage.googleapis.com" is not configured under images in your next.config.js` which indicates that the wrong or no next.config.js was loaded.

.env

```
...
NEXT_PUBLIC_IMAGE_LOADER=vercel
...
```

next.config.js

```
module.exports = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  /**
   * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
   */
  const vercelConfig = {
        deviceSizes: [320, 640, 750, 828, 1080],
        domains: ['storage.googleapis.com']
  }
  const cloudflarePagesConfig = {
        deviceSizes: [320, 640, 750, 828, 1080],
        loader: 'imgix',
        path: '/',
  }
  return process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_IMAGE_LOADER === 'cloudflare' ? cloudflarePagesConfig : vercelConfig
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: That condition will return vercelConfig even without reading .env, maybe `images:
{ domains: ['storage.googleapis.com'] }` solve your problem

Comment: @keyhan is correct, the images configurations need to go inside an `images` object in the config. See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#configuration-options.

Comment: Oh yeah that solves it thank you